# Let $X,Y \sim Exp(\lambda)$. Prove, by Jacobian

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X, Y$ are independent and $ X,Y \sim Exp(\lambda)$ Prove, by Jacobian :

$ X + Y \sim Gamma(2,\lambda)$

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: You also need the condition that $X$, $Y$ are independent. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Using Z=X+Y and W=X, so Y=Z-W. Det| D(x,y)/D(w,z)|= -1. 
fwz(wz)=fxy(x(w,z),y(w,z))*Det| D(x,y)/D(w,z)|->fx(w)*fy(z-w)(-1)

Answer (score 0):

Let $W:=X+Y,\,Z:=\tfrac{Y}{X}$ so $X=\tfrac{W}{1+Z},\,Y=\tfrac{WZ}{1+Z}$ and$$\lambda^2e^{-\lambda(x+y)}dxdy=\lambda^2we^{-\lambda w}dw\tfrac{2z}{(1+z)^3}dz.$$

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you need to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  The pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is given by $f(x) = \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-x/\lambda}$ for $x>0$.  Then the pdf of $X+Y$ is the convolution
$$
f_{X+Y}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y)f(x-y) \,dy = \int_0^x \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-y/\lambda} \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-(x-y)/\lambda}\ \,dy = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \int_0^x e^{-x/\lambda} \,dy = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} x e^{-x/\lambda},
$$
which is the desired pdf.

Comment: Your $1/\lambda$ is usually called $\lambda$.

Comment: True, but I chose this convention to match Wikipedia's definition of the gamma distribution

Comment: So you're taking $\lambda$ to [denote $\theta$ rather than $\beta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)? That's at odds with how $\lambda$ is defined in the OP's notation for exponential distributions.